# How to better express the idea of "advantages are supported by"

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, proper-nouns, existentials

I'm writing an essay about the benefits of eating only vegetables and fruits. This is my discussion statement, which links the supporting statement to my point of view.

> Advantages of vegetarian diet supported by such recognized organization
>   as Harvard's school of public health.

Can I say 'advantages are supported' and does this sentence make sense?

Comment: "The advantages of a vegetarian diet are supported by highly-regarded organizations, such as, Harvard School of Public Health." Not only could you say "advantages are supported," I would go as far as to say that you need to include "are" in your sentence.

Comment: Thanks for helpful information! Is it wrong to say recognized instead of highly-regarded? And could you explain me why it is necessary to put 'the' before advantages?

Comment: No, just a matter of style. And "the" is not necessary, either. Could be put in for emphasis or removed for conciseness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence does make sense with "are."  In fact, it doesn't make sense without "are," since it would have no main verb without "Are."

Here is the sentence as you should write it:

> Advantages of a vegetarian diet are supported by such recognized organizations as Harvard School of Public Health.

Here are other changes I made to the sentence:

- added the article "a" before "vegetarian diet"
- made organizations plural (if there is only one organization, just omit that part and write:

> Advantages of a vegetarian diet are supported by Harvard School of Public Health.

- Made "Harvard's school of public health" into "Harvard School of Public Health," which is the official name of the institution.